# Google Maps (ngmap directive) - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mean-stack

I know there are other similar questions but this is specific to my implementation using [ngmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngmap) in MEAN.js application.

Everything LOOKS like it is working the way it should but..

I get this error twice, when the page loads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined common.js:210
```

This is the error trace:

[image: google maps error]

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ng-map>
            <marker data-ng-repeat="device in panelController.model.projects.focused.devices"
                    position="{{[device.location.lat, device.location.lng]}}"
                    title="{{device.name}}"
                    animation="none"
                    draggable="false"
                    visible="true"
                    icon="modules/core/img/dashboard/marker.png">
            </marker>
        </ng-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the relevant controller code:

```
self.completeProjectLoad = function(project) {

      /* ======= New functionality to set bound box around markers ======= */
      function getLocations() {
        var locations = [];

        for (var i=0; i < project.devices.length; i++) {
          locations[i] = [project.devices[i].location.lat, project.devices[i].location.lng];
        }

        return locations;
      }

      var locatedDevices = getLocations();


      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      // create bounds around all located devices
      for (var i=0; i < locatedDevices.length; i++) {
        // get the latitude and longitude in the google maps expected format
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locatedDevices[i][0], locatedDevices[i][1]);
        //extend the bounds to contain each device
        bounds.extend(latlng)
      }

      // self.mapCenter = bounds.getCenter;

      /* ====== End of new functionality ======= */

      // Set the bounds of map to include all devices
      NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      })

        };
```

Which all comes together to create this:

[image]

As I said, things SEEM to be working fine, but I suspect this is an error that will later come to haunt me.

Appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `project.devices` an array of?  Are they Google LatLng objects or Markers, etc?  If so you should probably use a function like `getPosition()` or `lat()` / `lng()` to get the lat & lng values instead of relying on that lat and lng properties.

Comment: thanks but I don't see how that would help? project.devices are just objects that have lat and long properties, which I turn into Google LatLng objects in the second for loop, so that I can set the bounds.

Could you explain why that would solve the problem?

Comment: ok, if they're not Google Maps objects, then it isn't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ngmap but I have the exact same error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined  common.js:179

This was happenening when I did not have `center` or `zoom` option defined. I fixed by adding those options to map initialization.

```
# this is coffeescript
map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById('map-search')
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(42, -71)
  zoom: 10
)
```